# parse value is save in edittext field android

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, adapter

Here i have to parse the value from pervious activity to next activity successfully...now i wish to need that value is save in my edittext field...how can i develop this..

In my code have to orderid value is parsed from previous activity and displayed in this activity.here the orderid value is save in my edittext field automatically...how can i do...

in my previous activity code:

```
 Button btninsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View v) {
     String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InsertionExample.class);
i.putExtra(KEY_NAME, s);
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

this is my InsertionExample.java class:

```
public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;

static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    lblName.setText(orderid);


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText Orderid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderid);
            String orderid = Orderid.getText().toString();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

            request.addProperty(unameProp);
            PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
            idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
            idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(idProp);



              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try{
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  result.setText(response.toString());
             }
           catch(Exception e){

           }
              }
    });

    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

}

//Add animals into spinner dynamically
private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

 }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Here i have used below code for set the orderid on edittext field:idProp.setValue(orderid);/

```
            EditText Orderid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderid);
            String orderid = Orderid.getText().toString();
            PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
            idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
            idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(idProp);`
```

but i wish to need the edittext field have to automatically enter the my parsed orderid. 
(ie)

```
Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    lblName.setText(orderid);
```

This orderid is automatically enter the edittext box...how can i do..
please help me...give me some ideas.

Comment: You are using eclipse, right? Please press ctrl+shift+f and format your damn code before posting it. Also, it would be nice to say 'it won't compile' if it won't compile since you seem to have posted it like you want people to try it out or read thru it.

Answer (score 0):

The activity which wants to send the values to other will do this.....

```
Button bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn);
bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PutExtra.this, getExtra.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", et.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

The activity which is being called and want s the values will have to do this

```
override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getextra);

        EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String extra = intent.getStringExtra("text");      
        tv.setText(extra);
    }
```

Comment: please read my updated question and give me solution for this

Comment: ok.. what you exactly want to do with your edit text?

do you want to put the value you got from the getStringExtra() into the edit text

OR

you dont have to put that value in the edit text

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using startActivity(Intent i) use startActivityForResult(Intent i, key k). once you're done with your activity (call finish()) and go back to the root one, you will catch the 'result' in onActivityResult().

check this link if you need further info http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html